# Inequality with Big O notation

Tags: calculus

I have two non-negative real valued functions $f,g$ such that $f(x)\leq g(x)$ and I know that

$f(x) = (a(x))^2+ O(x^4)$

$g(x) = (b(x))^2+ O(x^4) $

for some other non-negative real valued functions $a,b$. Can I conclude from this that $a\leq b$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, both $a$ and $b$ could be small compared to $x^4$.